# RewriteRule to redirect to php file not working

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I just want a simple redirect to clean up the url's on a site.
e.g.
I want `ajhtestserver.com/registration/` to redirect to `ajhtestserver.com/registration.php`
It should be easy and I have successfully used .htaccess rewrites on other sites but for some reason it just will not work for me today.

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule ^registration[/]$ registration.php [NC,L] # Handle requests for "registration"
```

I am sure it is something simple that I am missing but I basically just copied what I have on other sites that work fine for me so I am confused as to why it just refuses to work for me here (gives me `The requested URL /ajhtestserver/registration/ was not found on this server.` error).  Just one of those days :(

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Yep, 500 Internal server errror

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess? Is it at same level as `registration.php`? Are there more rules as well? Finally is `/registration/` a directory?

Comment: .htaccess is in the root folder, as are the php files.  Currently that is the only rule.  /registration/ is not a directory.  See...weird right?

Comment: Try this rule: `RewriteRule ^foo /bar [L,R]` and then open `/foo` URL in your browser to see if it becomes `/bar` or not?

Comment: RewriteRule ^foo /bar.php [L,R] works.  But RewriteRule ^registration /registration.php [L,R] gives me an infinite redirect error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56371/discussion-between-adam-hollow-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

if you use apache ,first you should enable rewrite_mode in http.conf or ...\

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^registration/(.*)$ registration.php/$1 [L]
```

check .htaccess syntax or rewrite mode.

Comment: It's enabled.  Still getting the same error using your code.

Comment: in right I unknown You will doing by this Rule...!!! I copy This Rule from one of my projects and this code worked for me!!!

Comment: So after some testing it appears that it doesn't like it if the source and target are the same word.  It works fine if I try to redirect something like adam/ to registration.php but not registration/

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)[/]$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: See that should work...but it isn't.  Same error :(  And if I use something like RewriteRule ^registration.*$ /registration.php [R=301,L]  I get an infinite redirect error which is what should happen so I now it's reading the file.

Answer (score 0):

Well it didn't seem to like it when the redirect source word and target filename were the same word but this works...
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\ ]+)[/]?$ $1.php [NC,L]

And that is actually a better solution anyway as it doesn't require a separate rule for each page.

Though I never did figure out why it didn't like it the original way.

Comment: FYI you don't need the brackets on `[/]?`, `/?` is enough. Also not understanding why you are allowing a space in your character class (the backslash + space). Assuming you don't need the spaces, here's the same in more idiomatic regex: `^(?i)([a-z]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]`

Comment: The space was allowed because I copied the code from another site of mine that needed to allow spaces :)  Thanks for the streamlined code.